# PHP SSH2 in config command but function ssh2_connect doesn't exist

Tags: php, ssh

I use PHP 5.6.15 and wanted to use ssh2_connect for my project. phpinfo() shows among others this:

```
Configure Command   './configure' '--with-ssh2' '--with-apxs2' ...
```

but when I am trying to use ssh2_connect it throws an error that this function doesn't exist. What should I do then to make this work? Same in command line. I use DirectAdmin with CustomBuild 2.0.

My function to check:

```
if (!function_exists("ssh2_connect")) die("function ssh2_connect doesn't exist");
```

Comment: You should add a simple example of your code showing how you're calling the function.

Comment: <?php if (!function_exists("ssh2_connect")) die("function ssh2_connect doesn't exist");?>

Comment: Just tried to recomplile php with "--with-ssh2" - same result. In addition after checking php -m in console I can't see ssh2. Should I place some files in certain php dir?